# Some underlying elements visible in jQuery hover menu

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a hover quick menu that slides down when moving over the homepage link in List Views in my SharePoint Hosted App. Works fine, however some elements from the background are still visible through the menu, please refer below example (highlighted some with red circles):

[image]

My javascript includes the following:

```
$("div.KeuzeMenuHTML").css("opacity", "1.0");
$("div.KeuzeMenuHTML").css("background-color", "#dad4de");
$("div.KeuzeMenuHTML").css("position", "absolute");
```

How can I prevent this from happening? All help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: You need to set z-index on your overlay to be higher that the elements that can be seen through.

Comment: excellent thanks :). All the elements that get through were img tags. So I have set the z-index to those equal to "10" and the z-index of the div to "99". Please add your suggestion as an Answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set z-index on your overlay to be higher that the elements that can be seen through.